# ViewBag Assignment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, viewbag

I'm trying to pass a value from my database to the view in asp.net mvc, very simple stuff

```
    public ActionResult SettingsList() {


        using (podio_doc_db db = new podio_doc_db() ) {

            string app_id = db.Configs.Where(r => r.Key == "app.id").Select(r => r.Value).First();
            ViewBag["app_id"] = app_id;

        }

        return View();
    }
```

However I keep getting this error

```
Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Dynamic.DynamicObject'
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It should be this instead:

```
ViewBag.app_id = app_id;
```

ViewBag is a dynamic type, meaning you can add parameters, like app_id, at run-time.